# Reactive Forms two-way binding error: Cannot assign to read only property

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to achieve two way binding via the following code:

```js
export interface User {
  name: string;
  subscribed: boolean;
}

export class UserEditComponent implements OnInit {
  modifiedUser: User;
  userForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      subscribed: false
    });

    this.route.paramMap.switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
      return this.userService.getUser(params.get('id'));
    }).subscribe((user) => {
      this.modifiedUser = user;
      this.userForm.setValue({
        name: this.modifiedUser.name,
        subscribed: this.modifiedUser.subscribed
      });
    });

    this.userForm.valueChanges.subscribe((data) => {
      this.modifiedUser.subscribed = data.subscribed;
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="userForm">
  <textarea class="form-control" formControlName="name">{{modifiedUser.name}}</textarea>
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" formControlName="subscribed">
</form>
```

However, I'm always getting the error `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'subscribed' of object '[object Object]'` in the console as soon as the form appears. Any idea why?

Comment: I don't see `userForm` in your template. Can you create plunker?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's just a typo, `userForm` not `form`.

Comment: what is the value of _this.modifiedUser.subscribed_ you get from service

Comment: Could you show your `userService.getUser()` method?

Comment: `userService.getUser()` is a very long Apollo method that just returns `Observable<User>` and `this.modifiedUser.subscribed` is `false` in the above case, but can be true in other cases depending upon what the server returns.

Comment: What do you mean by `running my form`? Do you receive an error when you input some data in the textarea/click the checkbox or do you get an error rightaway? I am trying to reproduce your issue here, but everything works just fine.

Comment: I mean as soon as the page appears, the error appears on the console.

Comment: Hey, I tried to recreate your case in this [online editor](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nzzn2r), please look if this reproduction is appropriate, because I mostly copied your code and template, and mocked your `userService` to return an `Observable<User>`, and it just works fine

Comment: I will definitely look this afternoon, thank you. Is it worth mentioning that my object is being returned from an Apollo store? Might it be readonly because of that?

Comment: Well, I am not familiar with Apollo, but you mentioned that the service method call just returns an Observable of type User. Anyway, in your User interface the `subscribed` property is **not** `readonly`, so anyway, if Apollo does not somehow make the properties readonly at runtime, then I think it is not the matter.

Comment: And, by the way, did you try to make changes to the `name` property of the user when subscribing to `userForm.valueChanges`? This can shed some light on whether tall the properties are readonly

Comment: Hello, yes, I just did and got the exact same error :(

Comment: thanks you actually helped me with form.setValue ;) I didn't know how to set value after api response is ready.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this.modifiedUser` turned out to be indeed readonly. I had to simply make a deep copy of `user` object to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your module settings, do you have something like this?

```
StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {
        metaReducers,
        runtimeChecks: {
            strictStateImmutability: true,
            strictActionImmutability: false,
            strictStateSerializability: true,
            strictActionSerializability: true
        }
    })
```

I disabled the `strictActionImmutability` property, another alternative is to run `ng serve --prod` with the `--prod` flag, if you only run `ng serve` you need to set to false the `strictActionImmutability` property in your `runtimeChecks` object